# Changing scope object that depends on another scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, watch

In this example I have three scope objects

```
$scope.themes = [
  {
    name: 'Theme 1',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  {
    name: 'Theme 2',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
];

$scope.theme = {
  name: 'Default Theme',
  backgroundColor: '#000000',
};

$scope.config = {
  canvas: {
    fill: $scope.theme.backgroundColor,
  },
  elements: [
    {
      name: 'Circle',
      width: 200,
      height: 1000,
      fill: $scope.theme.backgroundColor
    },
  ]
};
```

An `ng-select` updates the value of `$scope.theme` (using `$scope.themes` as the `ng-options`). When `$scope.theme` changes, I want to update the value of `$scope.config`, where some of the attributes depend on a value of `$scope.theme`.

`$scope.config` has a `$watch()` running on it via a directive that makes changes to an element in the view, as a number of redacted attributes can be changed through the interface.

How do I trigger an update to `$scope.config` when `$scope.theme` changes, in order to trigger my `$watch`?

(It's worth noting that above is a much redacted version of `$scope.config`, where there are lots of items within `config.elements`.)

Comment: Are you realize that you don't really need any $watch at all as you can use object references?

Comment: Use references to take advantage of inheritance. Like: `$scope.theme = $scope.themes[0]` ... `$scope.config{ someProperty: $scope.theme.propertyName}`

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude theme properties from config and watch inside your directive theme and config at same time.

config:

```
$scope.config = {
  canvas: {
  },
  elements: [
    {
      name: 'Circle',
      width: 200,
      height: 1000
    },
    ...
  ]
};
```

your directive:

```
...
$scope.$watch('[theme, config]', function() {
    //do what you want with elements considering theme and config
}, true);
```

If you don't want to exclude theme properties from config you can just watch theme and change config respectively

```
$scope.$watch('theme', function(theme) {
    $scope.config.canvas.fill = theme.backgroundColor;
    ...
});
```

Comment: The idea is that anyone could fork this project and set up their own config (which will eventually be abstracted out into some interface or service), meaning the `$scope.theme` attributes need to remain the in `$scope.config` so that people are able to set up their own themes that alter the specific attributes they need.